# jQuery Strip White-space

Tags: jquery

I am not a web designer by any means, I am just attempting to make a change to something a legacy programmer put in place.

On a page the text field length is MAX 10 characters, what has happened is the source has changed the 10 character code on their page to include spaces, so customers are copying and pasting this code (including the spaces) which makes this 14 characters.

This is submitting truncated codes because people aren't paying attention (not their fault obviously).

I found some jQuery code to put in on the input on the form to strip the white-space on paste:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#dlc_code_txtbx0').bind('input', function() {
    $(this).val(function(_, v) {
      return v.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- This is my form field -->
<input type="text" id="dlc_code_txtbx0" name="dlc_code_txtbx0"
       class="cen" size="20" maxlength="10" placeholder="yNGsstK" />
```

When I copy and paste **aa bb cc dd ee** into the field, it removes the whitespace but still truncates the characters. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: u can input only 10 characters **aa bb cc d** ... when you paste string input take only first 10 and use your function...

Comment: @IvanKaraman correct but surely the strip whitespace on paste in the above jQuery should strip the whitespace before pasting so that the 'stripped' version is 10 characters. Or am I right in assuming it pastes it INTO the field and THEN strips it so it only strips what was initially pasted?

Comment: @Lunchie when u paste string he take only 10 characters with spaces than remove...

Comment: @Lynchie Well no, IMO the browser see the attribute first, and you can give it a try :
When input is "aa bb cc dd ee", the real value passed to your function is "aa bb cc d". Then the whitespaces are removed, that's why you have "aabbccd" as a result.

https://jsfiddle.net/7pxw3t8t/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add more characters then 10 because of the `maxlength` attribute on the `input`. If you'd remove that attribute, you can truncate the text in Javascript (jQuery) like so:

```
$(function(){
    $('#dlc_code_txtbx0').bind('input', function(){
        $(this).val(function(_, v){
            var outputValue = v.replace(/\s+/g, '');
            return outputValue.substr(0, 10); // substr will truncate the final string
        });
    });
});
```

Have a look at the [substr() reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).

Comment: np @Lynchie. Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: @Lynchie u can remove `maxlength` attr, add `data-max="10"` and in final truncate `10` replace with `$(this).data('max');` if you need multiple inputs with different maxlengts